# Primefaces reset messages in p:dialog

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am opening a popup on click of command link, and popup has a textbox and commandLink
whenever I press submit with textbox left blank, it shows validation msg, till now this is fine. Now if I close the popup  using cross icon on top right. then again click to showPopup, it show the error messages . I want to clear that messages and open fresh popup.
below is my code

```
<p:commandLink id="showDialogButton" styleClass="add_icon"
                                             value="ADD" onstart="#{dashboardBean.resetFoodPromoDTO()}" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" />
```

bean

```
 public void resetFoodPromoDTO(){
    foodPromoDTO=null;
        }
```

popup dialog

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}" styleClass="customized" widgetVar="dlg" draggable="true" closable="true" resizable="false" width="730">
<div class="popup_subheader">
<div class="float_left">Add - Food Promotion Activity</div>
<div class="float_right"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="popuptext">
            <div class="form-label"><label title="Project">Project:    </label></div>
            <div class="form-field"><p:inputText  id="projectName" value="#{dashboardBean.foodPromoDTO.project}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['validation.project.name']}"/>
            <p:message id="projeMsgId" for="projectName" autoUpdate="true"/>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="form-label"><label title="Promo Date">Promo Date:</label></div>

            <div class="btn_area_popup">
            <span>
            <p:commandLink id="submitButton" validateClient="true" value="Save" action="#{dashboardBean.addFoodPromotion()}" update="@form" onuccess="PF('dlg').hide();" ajax="true"/>
            </span>
            </div> 
            <div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the dialog

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" visible="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}" styleClass="customized" widgetVar="dlg" draggable="true" closable="true" resizable="false" width="730">
    <h:form id="dialog">
       <p:panel id="dialogBody">

            ....

       </p:panel>
   </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

You can update dialog with this code:

```
<p:commandLink id="showDialogButton" styleClass="add_icon"
     value="ADD" actionListener="#{dashboardBean.resetFoodPromoDTO()}" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" update=":dialog:dialogBody" />
```

You have to use `actionListener`.